# Is wrapping code into a closure a good habit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I a new to Angular and I just completed a tutorial from [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/) for beginners in Angular. Now in the second video the instructor of the course says that we are going to wrap our whole application code into a closure. The link to the video is below. He says this somewhere at 00:30. Now why is it a good practice to wrap our code into a closure?

[Link to the video](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/level/1/section/2/video/1)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Closures are primarily used to create private scope and avoid variables from leaking into the global scope.

Comment: Further explanation: since functions are the only things that create new scopes in JS, by using an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) you can create a scope just for your code that is less likely to pollute the global scope.

Comment: Dunno about "leaking", but certainly they are used to avoid global variables. As far as I'm aware, it's seen as good practice mostly for semantic reasons as it keeps code modular and therefore is easier to maintain.

Comment: @GregL— *eval* creates new scope (albeit a copy of the scope it's in) and new instances of host objects can too (e.g. frames, which also have their own global object). Also, *with* modifies the scope chain (though it doesn't create "new" scope).